# how to make single deep array out of couple arrays deep array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get an array of arrays back from the function pasted at the bottom.
The problem is i'm stuck on when an array will be present multiple times.

An example what I would like to get back is:

```js
[
  ['Batch', 'status', 'gewijzigd door', 'date', 'variable'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'jerry'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'john'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty']
]
```

But if it contains a biebs property. Then I run into a problem shown below.

```js
[
  ['Batch', 'status', 'gewijzigd door', 'date', 'variable'],
  [
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'jerry'], 
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'john']
  ],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
  ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
  [
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'jerry'], 
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'john']
  ]
]
```

I'm stuck on how I can solve this or tackle this result.   .flat() would also flatten the ones i would like to keep.
or is my function not build up in the right way?

Code is pasted below

```
import {CreateUrls, RemoveLastSlash} from '../../utils/Tools';


const List = (file, { bronUrlSplit, migrStatus }) => {

  const batchMigratie = file.map(d => {
    const { urlBron, subSite } = CreateUrls(d.Url, 'est', parseInt(bronUrlSplit))

    if (d.hasOwnProperty('biebs')) {
      const biebs = d.biebs.split(',')

      const test = biebs.map(element => {
        return [d.Batch, migrStatus, d.Titel, RemoveLastSlash(urlBron), RemoveLastSlash(subSite), element ];
      });
      return test
    }

    return [d.Batch, migrStatus, d.Titel, RemoveLastSlash(urlBron), RemoveLastSlash(subSite), 'empty' ];
  })

  batchMigratie.forEach(element => {
    console.log('element', element)
  });

  return [
    ['Batch', 'status', 'gewijzigd door', 'date', 'variable'],
    ...batchMigratie
  ]
}

export default List
```

Comment: Data transformation questions should always include the input and expected output of the transformation process. Please edit your question to include both.

Comment: Why mix mutable & immutable actions. Just use reduce to rebuild it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check for each array element if it contains another array. If yes, push each of its elements to  the result, else just the current element. Something like:

```js
const arr = [
    ['Batch', 'status', 'gewijzigd door', 'date', 'variable'],
    [
        ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'jerry'],
        ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'john']
    ],
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
    ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'empty'],
    [
        ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'jerry'],
        ['34', 'ready', 'projectname', '12-12-20', 'john']
    ]
];

function isArrayOfArrays(a){
    return a.every(x => Array.isArray(x));
}

function flattenArray(arr) {
    const result = [];
    for (const currElement of arr) {
        if (isArrayOfArrays(currElement)) {
            for (let innerArray of currElement) {
                result.push(innerArray);
            }
        } else {
            result.push(currElement);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(flattenArray(arr));
```

Comment: thanks to your way of solving, i rewrote my code to not have the innerArray anymore. So i removed the problem itself :)